# Generate logs for web application in Javascript

Tags: javascript, logging, web-applications, client

I have a use case in which I would like to generate logs for my JS web application, which could be stored as a file on the client-side (stored on the user's machine).

Therefore, I want to know that what approach can I follow for generating logs in JS?

Comment: In what? A browser? Browser-based JavaScript code can't write to arbitrary files on the user's computer. It would be a massive security problem.

Comment: *"I have seen libraries for Node JS but can't find any for vanilla JS."* Node.js isn't a variant of JavaScript. It's a host environment. So is a web browser. Both execute "vanilla" JavaScript, in their differing environments.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean you want to do this from browser-hosted JavaScript code, I'm afraid you can't. Browser-based JavaScript code can't write to arbitrary files on the user's computer. It would be a massive security problem.

You could keep a "log" in [web storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API), but note that web storage has size limits so you wouldn't want to let it grow too huge.

Here's a barebones logging function that adds to a log in local storage:

```
function log(...msgs) {
    // Get the current log's text, or "" if there isn't any yet
    let text = localStorage.getItem("log") || "";
    // Add this "line" of log data
    text += msgs.join(" ") + "\r\n";
    // Write it back to local storage
    localStorage.setItem("log", text);
}
```

Obviously you can then build on that in a bunch of different ways (log levels, date/time logging, etc.).

Comment: is indexDB a good place aswell? i mean its async and does not block the thread like localstorage

Comment: @Ifaruki - I have a bad habit of forgetting about IndexedDB. It won't work for all those people still (!) using IE, but now that Edge is based on Chromium, [support is good](https://caniuse.com/indexeddb2). So I'd say: Yes, absolutely! If you can dash off an example, please feel free to edit it into the above (it's a Community Wiki post) or post your own answer. If you do the latter, please ping me (SO will ping me for the former) -- I'm keen to see it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use local storage to simulate file :

Create id for each line of your "file" and store the number of the last line

```
function logIntoStorage (pMsg) {
    if (!pMsg) pMsg = "pMsg is not here !";
    if ((typeof pMsg) != "string") pMsg = "pMsg is Not a string:"+(typeof pMsg);        
    let logNb = "logNb";
    let padLong = 7;
    let strLg = "0";
    let lg = 0;
    let maxSize = 50; // max nb of lines in the log
    
    // Reading log num line
    strLg = localStorage.getItem(logNb);
    if(!strLg) { //logNb not stored yet
        lg = 0;
        strLg = "0";
        localStorage.setItem(logNb, lg.toString(10)); // store the number of cur line
    } else { // Read logNb from storage
        strLg = localStorage.getItem(logNb);
        lg = parseInt(strLg,10);
    } 
        
    if (lg >= maxSize) {
       lg = maxSize; // size limit nb lines.
       pMsg = "LIMIT SIZE REACHED";
    }


    // log msg into localStorage at logLine:0000#### 
    let s = ("0000000000000000"+strLg).substr(-padLong);  // padding zeros
    localStorage.setItem("logLine:"+s, pMsg);
    
    if (lg >= maxSize) return;
    lg++;  // point to the next line
    localStorage.setItem(logNb, lg.toString(10));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In modern Chrome you can actually "stream" data to the user's disk, after they give permission, thanks to the [File System Access](https://wicg.github.io/file-system-access/) API.

To do so, you have to request for a file to save to, calling `showSaveFilePicker()`.

Once you get the user's approval you'll receive a *handle* from where you'll be able to get a WriteableStream.
Once you are done writing, you just have to `.close()` the writer.

```
onclick = async () => {

  if( !("showSaveFilePicker" in self) ) {
    throw new Error( "unsupported browser" );
  }

  const handle = await showSaveFilePicker();
  const filestream = await handle.createWritable();
  const writer = await filestream.getWriter();
  // here we have a WritableStream, with direct access to the user's disk
  // we can write to it as we wish
  writer.write( "hello" );
  writer.write( " world" );
  // when we're done writing
  await writer.ready;
  writer.close();

};
```

[Live example](https://save-as-browser-js.glitch.me/).

Comment: Its a really interesting solution. I believe there won't be any storage size limitation except the disk size. I wanted to know if there are there any other downsides that you could know of like performance etc?

Comment: Well biggest downside is browser support, only Chrome as of today. Performance wise, it's as fast as your HDD can go. Regarding storage limitiation, indeed it should be disk size, though there might be limitations I don't know of.