# Using fetch to read and write files

Tags: javascript, html

In my code i've a file called "orca.txt" it is just a number writen in this.
it looks like:

> 2300

I use fetch to read this number, i get it with:

> fetch('orca.txt')
>
> .then(response => response.text())
>
> .then(textString => { contador=textString; });

It works very well, but then after i need to increase the value from the var contador,
so I use contador++; after i wanna to save this new value into the file "orca.txt"

i've tried this:

> contador++;
>
> var ct=contador.toString();
>
> fetch("orca.txt",{method:'POST', body:ct})
>
> .then (response => response.text());

but when i refresh the page or open in server the file orca.txt the value is same.

Can anyone help me how to write a value into a file (server file, no user file) using POST method?

Comment: You cannot write to files using frontend scripts. You need a dedicated backend for that.  For example if you use Node JS you need a route that uses `fs` (in order to write to your files on server) Or, if you use PHP you could have a `writeFile.php` that receives that POST data and overwrites your file.

Comment: If you ask *"but why"* - imagine you arrive to some website - some strange one, and suddenly someone starts writing files on your hard drive. That's pretty dangerous from a security perspective - therefore not something JS (on the frontend) is suited for.

Comment: can you help me to write it in PHP @RokoC.Buljan cause i'm using just JS

Comment: Of course I can! I'll put up some demo soon

Comment: can i use fwrite? @RokoC.Buljan i'm looking for something in PHP. Thanks at all

Comment: Before you going writing a server, there *are* ways to persist data in the browser: localStorage, indexedDb etc. Do you really need to save it as a text file?

Comment: @seesharper not really.. Imagine i've many users of this page, after all my code i create a pdf file named "ORC001", "ORC002", ORC003" for each user that accesses the page. i'm trying to use a file to register the id of "ORC???.pdf".. so i've written it in a text file... i don't know how to do it exactly...

Comment: When an user opens the page and generate the pdf, i want to increase its value. For the next user gets "ORC004" eg.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Actually [you can very well write on user's disk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65122664/3702797) (after asking for their permission).

Comment: @Kaiido yes, you could also use the `download` attribute on a dynamic button element to save arbitrary files. And also use the computer webcam - with the user consent...

Comment: The download wouldn't allow to write directly on disk, and the camera is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @Kaiido yes it would actually. Even without a "save as" prompt. That's what I use to save images, text files and other stuff to the user's *downloads* folder. Am I missing something? And yes, a User permission is very relevant.

Comment: Yes, you are missing that when you do this you are only *writing* in the memory, and that then this memory is being *fetched* by the browser before it's saved on the user's disk. This means that you have to have all your data accessible in the memory before being able to save it to the disk, and thus can't stream data there, nor keep an open handle to the file there, nor *edit* a file. *Writing to the disk* directly allows all these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using **PHP** and [file_put_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) and JS's [**Fetch API**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) with [FormData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)

[image]

Create an `index.html` file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>DEMO</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="increment" type="button">INCREMENT</button>
    <input id="counter" type="text" readonly>

    <script>
        const EL_increment = document.querySelector("#increment");
        const EL_counter = document.querySelector("#counter");
        let counter = 0;

        const incrementCounter = () => {
            counter = parseInt(counter) + 1;
            const FD = new FormData();
            FD.append("counter", counter);
            fetch("saveCounter.php", {
                method: 'post',
                body: FD
            }).then(data => data.json()).then((res) => {
                EL_counter.value = res.counter;
            });
        };

        const init = async () => {
            EL_increment.addEventListener("click", incrementCounter);
            counter = await fetch('counter.txt').then(response => response.text());
            EL_counter.value = counter;
        };

        init();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

create `counter.txt` file:

```
2300
```

Create a `saveCounter.php` file:

```php
<?php

$response = ["status" => "error"];

if (isset($_POST["counter"]) && file_put_contents("counter.txt", $_POST["counter"])) {
    $response = ["status" => "success", "counter" => $_POST["counter"]];
}

echo json_encode($response);

exit;
```

Spin up your localhost server or for a quick test using `cli-server` run from terminal:

```sh
php -S localhost:8081
```

and head to http://localhost:8081 to try it out

Comment: You're welcome @MarioAugusto. If you have questions regarding the code... feel free to ask.

Comment: can i do it without an 'addEventListener("click", incrementCounter);'? because i have a function called generatePDF() and i wanna the post (fecth) occurs after the user runs the function... it's not possible? PHP runs first than javascript... but if i have a variable incrementCounter... how can i  set without addEventListener...? (i don't know if you undestand)

Comment: @MarioAugusto sure it's possible! It's right there in the code! Simply call `incrementCounter();` right inside your  `generatePDF` function. And, logically, remove the now unnecessary `EL_increment.addEventListener("click", incrementCounter);` line.

Comment: thanks... i've confused cause you used 'const name = () => {' but i now i understand... i'll try

Comment: @MarioAugusto yes, `const incrementCounter = () => {` is just an Arrow Function. Similar as doing: `function incrementCounter () {` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: it works!! i'm really happy. Thank you.. Now i undestand that incrementCounter is a function not just a variable! It's great

Comment: my <script> is after </body>

Comment: Sorry, I was commenting on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67377937/383904) Mistakenly I've pasted it here.

Comment: the last doubt... you use "await" it doesnt work to me... i've written fecth('orca.txt).then(response=>response.text()).then(textString=> {contador=textString}); than after, i've written document.getElementById('label1').innerHTML=contador... (like you used EL_counter.value = counter; to set the initial value.... but innerHTML doesnt work

Comment: @MarioAugusto any errors in Developer Tools Console?

Comment: Tomorrow i'll look for the error... but it's great.. the big ploblem is solved!